# Реализация секундомера для пятнашек

Tags: java

Доброе время суток! Вас беспокоит начинающий java кодер. У меня есть задание которое нужно сдать на сессие. Необходимо написать программу пятнашки. Помимо базового функционала в программе должно быть реализована возможность статистики пользователей по времени которое человек играл. саму программу пятнашек я нашел готовою, ну и немного преобразовал. Загвоздка в создании секундомера. Я так понял что данные с него необходимо выводить в JLabel. Сам секундомер нашел на этом сайте. Но при попытке вывода его в JLabel выдает ошибку:

> `pt.java:155: cannot resolve symbol
> symbol: variable topLabel
> location: class pt
> topLabel.setText(minute + ":" + seconds);`

Сам код программы далее(просьба не обращать внимание на излишние комментарии).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.util.*;

public class pt extends JFrame { // класс pt называют прямым наследником класса JFrame

    /*При построении интерфейсов нужны компоненты-контерйнеры, которые будут содержать другие компоненты
    пользовательского интерфейса. В Swing одним из таких компонентов-контейнеров является JPanel.
    Класс GridLayout позволяет размещать компоненты в контейнере в виде таблицы. В каждой ячейке таблицы может быть размещен только один компонент.
    Количество строк и столбцов таблицы определяется или в конструкторе, или вызовом методов setColumns и setRows.*/

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 2, 2));

    /*Главное меню JMenuBar - компонент графического интерфейса Java Swing*/

    private JMenuBar menu = null;
    private final String fileItems[] = new String [] {"New", "Statistic", "Exit"};
    private static Random generator = new Random(); // генератор случайных чисел
    private int[][] numbers = new int[4][4];

    /* -=== Опредиление клиентской ширины екрана ===- */

    //опредиление размеров екрана
    //Класс Toolkit является абстрактным суперклассом для всех реализаций AWT.
    //Порожденные от него классы используются для привязки различных компонент конкретных реализаций.

    /*Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); //Получение ссылки на Toolkit
    Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize(); // Определяем разрешение екрана в пикселях
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height; // получаем высоту
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width; // получаем ширину*/

    /* -=== /Опредиление клиентской ширины екрана ===- */

    public pt() {
        setTitle("Пятнашки"); //Заголовок окна

        /* -=== 2 - ой вариант задания размеров и положения окна ===- */

        // Первые 2-а значения метода setBonds устанавливают положение на екране по x и y;
        // Вторые 2-а устанавливают ширину и высоту получаемого окна
        // setBounds(200, 200, 300, 300);

        /* -=== /2 - ой вариант задания размеров и положения окна ===- */

        setSize (300, 300); // Задаем размеры окна приложения
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Окно приложения центрируется относительно экрана

        setResizable(true); // задаем возможность растягивать окно
        createMenu(); //инициализируем меню
        setJMenuBar(menu); // добавляем панель меню к окну
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // закрываем программу при закрытии окна

        //Класс container — прямой подкласс класса component, и наследует все его методы.
        //Каждый компонент перед выводом на экран помещается в контейнер (container). Контейнер "знает", как разместить компоненты на экране.
        /*Создав компонент — объект класса Component или его расширения, следует добавить его к предварительно созданному объекту класса container
        или его расширения одним из методов add (). */

        Container container = getContentPane();
        init();
        panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white); // устанавливаем цвет фона
        container.add(panel); // добавление компонентов в контейнер
        repaintField();
        JLabel();
        Timer();
    }

    public void init() { // описание метода init
        int[] invariants = new int[16]; // инициализируем массив с именем invariants из 16 елементов - лт 0 до 15

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // перебираем елементы i от 0 до 3
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { // перебираем елементы j от 0 до 3
                numbers[i][j] = 0; // указываем что перебор в цыкле начинаеться с нулевого елемента
                invariants[i*4 + j] = 0; // определяем какой из 16 елементов будет = 0
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) { // перебираем елементы i от 1 до 15
            int k; //обьявляем переменную k типа int
            int l; //обьявляем переменную l типа int
            do { // цыкл с послеусловием
                k = generator.nextInt(100) % 4; // переменной k присваиваем произвольное число от 0 до 100 деленное по модулю на 4
                l = generator.nextInt(100) % 4; // переменной l присваиваем произвольное число от 0 до 100 деленное по модулю на 4
            }
            while (numbers[k][l] != 0); // до тех пор пока двумерный массив numbers не равен 0
            numbers[k][l] = i; // присваиваем двумерному массиву numbers значение i в цикле от 1 до 15
            invariants[k*4+l] = i; // определяем позиции всех елементов кроме 0 на сетке
        }

        boolean change = true; // в булевую переменную change заносим значение true
        int counter = 1; // инициализируем переменную counter типа int и присваеваем ей 1
        while (change) {
            change = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (invariants[i] != i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                        if (invariants[j] == i) {
                            int temp = invariants[i];
                            invariants[i] = invariants[j];
                            invariants[j] = temp;
                            change = true;
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            int temp = numbers[0][0];
            numbers[0][0] = numbers[3][3];
            numbers[3][3] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void JLabel() {
        Border solidBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1); // создаем границу черного цвета
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12); // задаем тип шрифта, и его размер
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel(); // создаем обьект topLabel типа JLabel
        //topLabel.setText("Здесь будет секундомер");
        topLabel.setBorder(solidBorder); // устанавливаем границу
        topLabel.setFont(font); // устанавливаем тип текста
        topLabel.setForeground(Color.RED); // Устанавливаем цвет текста
        menu.add(topLabel); // добавляем JLabel на пенель menu
    }

    public void Timer() {
        int seconds = 0, minutes = 0;
        while (true) {
            seconds++;
            if (minutes != 0)
                topLabel.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds); // текст в JLabel
            //System.out.print(minutes + ":");
            //System.out.println(seconds);
            if (seconds == 59) {
                seconds = -1;
                minutes++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void repaintField() {  //метод расстановки кнопок со значениями на сетке
        panel.removeAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(numbers[i][j]));
                button.setFocusable(false);
                panel.add(button);
                button.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(0.1059322f, 0.5221239f, 0.8862745f)); // устанавливаем цвет кнопок
                if (numbers[i][j] == 0) {
                    button.setVisible(false); // сокрытие нулевого елемента массива
                } else
                    button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
            }
        }

        panel.validate();
    }

    public boolean checkWin() { //метод проверки выигрыша
        boolean status = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i == 3 && j > 2) //проверка на то что последняя ячейка в сетке пустая
                    break;
                if (numbers[i][j] != i * 4 + j + 1) { //проверка на соотвествие элементам массива координатам в сетке
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

        for (int i = 0; i < fileItems.length; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(fileItems[i]);
            JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
            item.setActionCommand(fileItems[i].toLowerCase());
            item.addActionListener(new NewMenuListener());
            fileMenu.add(item);
            fileMenu.add(separator);
        }
        //fileMenu.insertSeparator(1);

        menu.add(fileMenu);
    }

    private class NewMenuListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if ("exit".equals(command)) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if ("statistic".equals(command)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!", "Поздравляем", 1);
            }
            if ("new".equals(command)) {
                init();
                repaintField();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
            button.setVisible(false);
            String name = button.getText();
            change(Integer.parseInt(name));
        }
    }

    public void change(int num) { // передаем в качестве входящих параметров метода change переменную num типа int
        int i = 0, j = 0; // присваиваем перменным i и j типа int значение равное 0
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) { // перебираем елементы k от 0 до 3
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) { // перебираем елементы l от 0 до 3
                if (numbers[k][l] == num) { // если массив numbers[k][l] равный переменной num то,
                    i = k; // переменную i приравниваем переменной k
                    j = l; // переменную j приравниваем переменной l
                }
            }
        }

        /*реализация логики сдвигов кнопок на сетке 4 Х 4*/
        //сдвиг вверх по строкам
        if (i > 0) { // условие отвечающее за то можно ли сдвинуть кнопку по строке
            if (numbers[i - 1][j] == 0) { //сравниваем значение координат элемента массива с кнопкой которая в текущем массиве равна нулю
                numbers[i - 1][j] = num; //присваиваем переменной num значение координат элемента массива
                numbers[i][j] = 0; //присваеваем нулевой элемент массива в ячейку которая перед этим смещалась в ноль
            }
        }
        //сдвиг вниз по строкам
        if (i < 3) {
            if (numbers[i + 1][j] == 0) {
                numbers[i + 1][j] = num;
                numbers[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        //сдвиг влево по столбцам
        if (j > 0) {
            if (numbers[i][j - 1] == 0) {
                numbers[i][j - 1] = num;
                numbers[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        //сдвиг вправо по столбцам
        if (j < 3) {
            if (numbers[i][j + 1] == 0) {
                numbers[i][j + 1] = num;
                numbers[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        repaintField();
        if (checkWin()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!", "Поздравляем", 1);
            init();
            repaintField();
            setVisible(false);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        JFrame app = new pt();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Я так понял, что метод Timer не видит обьект topLabel. Но почему не понятно.
Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: setTitle("Пятнашки - Евгений Холевчук"); //Заголовок окна
epic fail

Comment: реализация таймера - фантастическая

Comment: вот все говорят, это просто для контрольной/лабораторной/курсовой/дипломной, а я супер-пупер мастер, только не в этой области, в итоге никто толком ничего и не знает. Напомнило одно сравнение (преподаватель рассказывал)

Мать посылает сына за хлебом, тот приносит чек, а хлеба нету.

 -а где же хлеб ?

 -а зачем он ? Я чек принес, значит хлеб купил.

Так и со знаниями, диплом есть, а знаний, к сожалению нету

Comment: Если нечего сказть по сути, просьба не засорять тему. А то веришь ты тому что я в другой области работаю или не веришь, это уже твои личные проблемы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

много кода, причем не твоего, разбираться не хочется, сессия, а ты просишь, что бы тебе яву с 0 начали объяснять, со счетчиком все просто, есть в яве специальный класс Timer, его ты инициализируешь в начале игры и вызываешь метод старт, в конце игры, вызываешь метод стоп и  выводишь результат в любом удобном виде

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!
setTitle("Пятнашки - Евгений Холевчук"); //Заголовок окна epic fail
 - ))) согласен;
То что в сути это все говнокод - я понимаю. Но увы это мне нужно только для универа. Я сам работаю мидл HTML верстальщиком...по сему мне и толком ничего не ясно в Яве. Это просто курсовой.